# Можно ли вернуть пустой константный запрос?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Например, есть такой запрос

```
SELECT 0
UNION
SELECT 1
UNION
SELECT <что либо (КОНСТАНТА) или НИЧЕГО по условию>
```

То есть запрос должен вернуть 2 или 3 записи. Подскажите как.

Comment: Если условие не выполнится - запрос вернёт 2 записи. Если выполнится - три. Если третий запрос возвращает 0 или 1 - используйте UNION ALL

Comment: @Zufir какое условие?

Comment: <что либо или НИЧЕГО по условию> - ну вот это условие. WHERE чего-нибудь-там

Comment: @Zufir, вы запрос готовый предложите, а то я не понимаю о чем вы

Comment: @Zufir, я ведь в заголовке написал, что запрос константный. То есть там нет никаких WHERE, запроса к базе не будет. Вернет он какую нибудь константу или ничего.

Comment: `UNION SELECT 2 WHERE @ConditionVariable=1` - например так.Если не будет WHERE - что значит "По условию"?

Comment: @iRumba а сколько он у Вас записей возвращает?

Comment: В заголовке и вопросе нестыковка какая-то. `Можно ли вернуть пустой запрос?` и `Запрос должен вернуть 2 или 3 записи, подскажите как`

Comment: @iRumba where проверяет не обязательно в БД. `select 5 where 1=0` ничего не вернет. подставьте переменные/константы по вкусу

Comment: @Zufir, оформите как ответ, пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
SELECT 0
UNION
SELECT 1
UNION 
SELECT 2 WHERE @ConditionVariable=1
```